# How is divergence of vector field not commutative?

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis

I came across a line in a textbook on calculus that [image]

where v defines a differentiable vector field
How can this be the case?

Comment: $\nabla\cdot\vec{v}$ is a number while $\vec{v}\cdot\nabla$ is an operator. They are clearly different.

Comment: This happens when abusing notation ...

Comment: Since $\nabla.\vec{u}$ is a scalar, maybe they meant that for an arbitrary $\vec{v}$, $$(\nabla.\vec{u})\vec{v}\ne\vec{u}\,.(\nabla\vec{v})$$ by the way, that's a terrible way of saying such thing